# How to filter on a nullable type in the solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

When searching for *DateTime* in the solution explorer, it lists all `DateTime` properties, but no `DateTime?` properties. When searching for *DateTime?* or *Nullable<DateTime>* I don't get the desired result.

When searching for e.g. *BirthDate*, I get the desired result: *BirthDate : DateTime?*

Is it possible to filter on a nullable type?

Comment: have you tried `Nullable\`1[[DateTime]]`

Comment: @DanielA.White I hadn't, but I get "No results found." with that query.